# Can't render Card from react-native-elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I have been simply trying to render a card from `react-native-elements` UI library. Here is the documentation that I've been looking through and literally copied and pasted from: https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/1.2.0/card

Here is my `Deal` component:

```js
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

const Deal = () => {
    const users = [
        {
            name: 'brynn',
            avatar: 'https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png',
        },
    ]
    return (
        <View>
            <Card containerStyle={{ padding: 0 }}>
                {users.map((u, i) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem
                            key={i}
                            roundAvatar
                            title={u.name}
                            leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: u.avatar } }}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </Card>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Deal
```

Here is my `SecondScreen` component in which I am trying to render `Deal`:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Step from '../components/Step'
import MyCarousel from '../components/MyCarousel'
import Ratings from '../components/Ratings'
import Deal from '../components/Deal'

export default function SecondScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const { image } = route.params

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text
                    style={{ fontSize: '16px', marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 15 }}
                >
                    Daily Deals
                </Text>
                <View
                    style={{
                        borderBottomColor: 'black',
                        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                    }}
                />
                <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                    <Deal />
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is what it renders at the end:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have decided to use another component in the meantime. This seems like possibly deprecated component or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex` or `height` for `<View />`

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 10 }}>
    <Deal />
</View>
```

Comment: Just tried them both and still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Deal` component, you have a `<View />` wrapper around the `<Card />` component.  The one inside `Deal` file, NOT the one wrapping it in `SecondScreen` file.

Have you tried removing that excess `<View />`?

If you want to keep that `<View />`, have you tried giving that specific `<View />` a `style={{ height: 100px }}` or `style={{ flex: 1 }}` property?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I just tried them both out (without View and with View with the styles) and still having trouble having it render. :( I am using another component in the meantime.